# How does SARS-CoV-2 spread from cell to cell in the lung?

Tags: coronavirus

This virus exits the cell using exocytosis after assembling golgi vesicles which contain the virus by fusing with the cell membrane.

In the case of infected pneumocytes, I imagine that the virus could then exit into the alveolus and infect other pneumocytes using again the interaction of the S protein with ACE2 or it could exit into the blood and spread to other pneumocytes in a 'miliary' fashion like TB.
Is either or both the main mechanism of spread in the lung?
Does lymphatic spread play any role?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted to MedicalSciences.SE. In the future, please choose a single site to submit your question to. Cross-posting is rude.